# How do I prevent Wireless devices showing up as Wired devices on a 2-router-network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, lan

I have 2 Netgear Routers:

- Netgear ADSL Modem + Router with Genie
- Netgear WGR614 N-150

I have the internet connected to my home network devices via the modem, and WGR614(LAN).

The WGR614 is connected via LAN to the modem, and is only being used for wireless connection as a Access Point... I have disabled it's DHCP and kept it on the same IP range as the modem router.

And so, since the WGR614 is connected via lan, all devices connected via the WGR614 are showing up as "Wired Devices", even if they're wireless! I'm not using the WGR614 for wired connections, and still these devices are being showed up in the Connected Devices as "Wired Devices".

I need these devices to be listed normally under wireless because I can't keep logs of wired devices in my modem settings. For this I checked the setting on Genie LAN webpage and it supports wireless connection logs only.

That's mostly all.

Comment: Bad luck I'd say. The Genie is not supposed to inspect the WGR. There's not even anything in the IP packets that could give a hint.

Comment: ok. Then I guess I'll buy a separate repeater... Thanks!